# Spinner Value is not preserved for 2nd spinner onStart

Tags: android, onstart

I have two spinners, the information on the 2nd spinner is based on the 1st spinner selection
EXAMPLE
SPINNER 1 PROTEIN DAIRY FRUITS
IF SPINNER 1 IS SET WITH PROTEIN then SPINNER 2 EGG CHICKEN
IF SPINNER 1 IS SET WITH FRUITS then SPINNER 2 APPLE ORANGE

Last value selected SPINNER 2 ORANGE

Now I want to preserve the last values selected of the SPINNER1 and SPINNER2, I am using SharedPreferences to accomplish this, it works as expected for SPINNER 1 FRUITS
Position 2 however for SPINNER2 it does not set the last value selected even though the position is correct position 1  when it is called `onStart();` it selects the 1st value that is on the array APPLE

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

```
public class TEST extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefStoreInfo, sharedPrefGetInfo;

    public String keyRow1, getBackInformationRow1;

    String concatenateInfoRow1, currentDateString, concatenateInfoTotals, getBackInformationTotals,
            getBackInformationParseTotals[],

            getBackInformationParseRow1[]

    ;

    // declare adaptors to bind with spinners
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerFoodCategoryRow1Adapter;

    // declare the references for the UI elements
    public static Spinner spinnerFoodCategoryRow1,  

                spinnerFoodNameRow1,;

    private String[] oilsFoodInformation, fruitsFoodInformation, foodCategoryInformation;

    TextView day, date, textViewProteinRow1, textViewCarbsRow1, textViewFatRow1, textViewCaloriesRow1,

            textViewDailyTotalProtein, textViewDailyTotalCarbs, textViewDailyTotalFat, textViewDailyTotalCalories

    ;

    EditText editRow1;

    String textInputRow1, textInputRow1ResultProtein, textInputRow1ResultCarbs, textInputRow1ResultFat,
            textInputRow1ResultCalories,

            dailyTotalProtein, dailyTotalCarbs, dailyTotalFat, dailyTotalCalories

    ;

    int gramsEditTextInputParseRow1;

    double resultIntProteinRow1, resultIntCaloriesRow1, resultIntCarbsRow1, resultIntFatRow1,;

    double proteinInfoRule3Row1, carbsInfoRule3Row1, fatInfoRule3Row1, caloriesInfoRule3Row1,;

    public String foodNameTempRow1,;

    double canolaProtein = 0;
    double canolaCarbs = 0;
    double canolaFat = 1;
    double canolaCalories = 8.84;
    double coconutOilProtein = 0;
    double coconutOilCarbs = 0;
    double coconutOilFat = 1;
    double coconutOilCalories = 8.62;
    double cornProtein = 0;
    double cornCarbs = 0;
    double cornFat = 1;
    double cornCalories = 9;
    double applesProtein = 0;
    double applesCarbs = 0;
    double applesFat = 0;
    double applesCalories = 0;
    double apricotsProtein = 0;
    double apricotsCarbs = 0;
    double apricotsFat = 0;
    double apricotsCalories = 0;
    double bananasProtein = 0;
    double bananasCarbs = 0;
    double bananasFat = 0;
    double bananasCalories = 0;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.food_tracker_layout); -
            editRow1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRow1);


            textViewProteinRow1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewProteinR1);
            textViewCarbsRow1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCarbsR1);
            textViewFatRow1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewFatR1);
            textViewCaloriesRow1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCaloriesR1);

            spinnerFoodCategoryRow1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1R1);
            spinnerFoodNameRow1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2R1);

            initializeSpinnerFoodCategoryAdapters();

            // CHANGE THE FONT SIZE OF SPINNER FOOD CATEGORY
            spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // Change the selected item's text color
                    ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    ((TextView) view).setTextSize(12);

                    getSelectedFoodCategoryRow1(); // **

                    // THIS IS TO CHANGE THE FONT SIZE OF SPINNER FOOD NAME
                    spinnerFoodNameRow1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            // Change the selected item's text color
                            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            ((TextView) view).setTextSize(10);

                            getSelectedFoodNameRow1();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        }
                    });// end
                                        } // end

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });


        }// End Main

    public void initializeSpinnerFoodCategoryAdapters() {

        Resources res = getResources();

        spinnerFoodCategoryRow1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                res.getStringArray(R.array.SpinnerArrayInfoFoodCategory));
        spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.setAdapter(spinnerFoodCategoryRow1Adapter);

        spinnerFoodCategoryRow2Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                res.getStringArray(R.array.SpinnerArrayInfoFoodCategory));
        spinnerFoodCategoryRow2.setAdapter(spinnerFoodCategoryRow2Adapter);

    }

    public String getSelectedFoodCategoryRow1() {

        Resources res = getResources();

        String selectedspinnerFoodCategoryRow1 = (String) spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItem();

        sharedPrefStoreInfo = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // FOOD NAME OILS ROW1
        if (spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {

            spinnerFoodNameRow1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    res.getStringArray(R.array.SpinnerArrayInfoOils));
            spinnerFoodNameRow1.setAdapter(spinnerFoodNameRow1Adapter);

            int selectedPosition = spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefStoreInfo.edit();
            editor.putInt("ROW1", selectedPosition);
            editor.commit();

            return selectedspinnerFoodCategoryRow1;
        }

        if (spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2) {

            spinnerFoodNameRow1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    res.getStringArray(R.array.SpinnerArrayInfoFruits));
            spinnerFoodNameRow1.setAdapter(spinnerFoodNameRow1Adapter);
            int selectedPosition = spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefStoreInfo.edit();
            editor.putInt("ROW1", selectedPosition);
            editor.commit();

            return selectedspinnerFoodCategoryRow1;
        }

        return selectedspinnerFoodCategoryRow1;

    }

    // RETRIEVE INFO FOODNAME FROM THE SPINNER ROW1
    public String getSelectedFoodNameRow1() {

        Resources res = getResources();

        String selectedspinnerFoodCategoryRow1 = (String) spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItem();
        String selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1 = (String) spinnerFoodNameRow1.getSelectedItem();

        foodCategoryInformation = res.getStringArray(R.array.SpinnerArrayInfoFoodCategory);

        oilsFoodInformation = res.getStringArray(R.array.SpinnerArrayInfoOils);
        fruitsFoodInformation = res.getStringArray(R.array.SpinnerArrayInfoFruits);

        for (int n = 0; n < foodCategoryInformation.length; n++) {

            // SELECTS INFORMATION ON THE FOOD CATEGORY SPINNER
            if (spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItemPosition() == n) {

                // SELECT TYPE OF FOOD CATEGORY
                switch (selectedspinnerFoodCategoryRow1) {

                case "OILS":

                    foodCategoryTempRow1 = selectedspinnerFoodCategoryRow1;

                    // ITERATE THE ARRAY TO SELECT THE FOOD NAME ITEM IN OILS
                    for (int i = 0; i < oilsFoodInformation.length; i++) {

                        // SELECT FOOD NAME BASED ON POSITION IN DAIRY
                        if (spinnerFoodNameRow1.getSelectedItemPosition() == i) {

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefStoreInfo.edit();
                            editor.putInt("ROW1-OILS", i);
                            editor.commit();
                            if (selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1.equals("Canola")) {

                                // ASSIGN THE FOOD NAME SELECTED TO A
                                // foodNameTempRow1 VARIABLE
                                foodNameTempRow1 = selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1;

                                // ASSIGN INFO TO VARIABLES THAT WILL BE USED ON
                                // THE CALCULATION CLICK BUTTON
                                proteinInfoRule3Row1 = canolaProtein;
                                carbsInfoRule3Row1 = canolaCarbs;
                                fatInfoRule3Row1 = canolaFat;
                                caloriesInfoRule3Row1 = canolaCalories;

                            } // end IF CANOLA

                            if (selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1.equals("Coconut Oil")) {

                                // ASSIGN THE FOOD NAME SELECTED TO A
                                // foodNameTempRow1 VARIABLE
                                foodNameTempRow1 = selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1;

                                proteinInfoRule3Row1 = coconutOilProtein;
                                carbsInfoRule3Row1 = coconutOilCarbs;
                                fatInfoRule3Row1 = coconutOilFat;
                                caloriesInfoRule3Row1 = coconutOilCalories;

                            } // end IF Coconut Oil

                            if (selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1.equals("Corn")) {

                                // ASSIGN THE FOOD NAME SELECTED TO A
                                // foodNameTempRow1 VARIABLE
                                foodNameTempRow1 = selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1;

                                proteinInfoRule3Row1 = cornProtein;
                                carbsInfoRule3Row1 = cornCarbs;
                                fatInfoRule3Row1 = cornFat;
                                caloriesInfoRule3Row1 = cornCalories;

                            } // end IF Corn

                        } // end if OILS POSITION

                    } // end for OILS

                    break;

                case "FRUITS":

                    // ASSIGN THE FOOD CATEGORY SELECTED TO A
                    // foodCategoryTempRow1 VARIABLE
                    foodCategoryTempRow1 = selectedspinnerFoodCategoryRow1;

                    // ITERATE THE ARRAY TO SELECT THE FOOD NAME ITEM IN DAIRY
                    for (int i = 0; i < fruitsFoodInformation.length; i++) {

                        // SELECT FOOD NAME BASED ON POSITION IN DAIRY
                        if (spinnerFoodNameRow1.getSelectedItemPosition() == i) {

                            if (selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1.equals("Apples")) {
                                // ASSIGN THE FOOD SELECTED TO A
                                // foodNameTempRow1Dairy VARIABLE
                                foodNameTempRow1 = selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1;

                                // ASSIGN INFO TO VARIABLES THAT WILL BE USED ON
                                // THE CALCULATION CLICK BUTTON
                                proteinInfoRule3Row1 = applesProtein;
                                carbsInfoRule3Row1 = applesCarbs;
                                fatInfoRule3Row1 = applesFat;
                                caloriesInfoRule3Row1 = applesCalories;

                            } // end if Apples

                            if (selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1.equals("Apricots")) {

                                foodNameTempRow1 = selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1;

                                proteinInfoRule3Row1 = apricotsProtein;
                                carbsInfoRule3Row1 = apricotsCarbs;
                                fatInfoRule3Row1 = apricotsFat;
                                caloriesInfoRule3Row1 = apricotsCalories;

                            } // end if Apricots

                            if (selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1.equals("Bananas")) {

                                foodNameTempRow1 = selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1;

                                proteinInfoRule3Row1 = bananasProtein;
                                carbsInfoRule3Row1 = bananasCarbs;
                                fatInfoRule3Row1 = bananasFat;
                                caloriesInfoRule3Row1 = bananasCalories;

                            } // end if Bananas

                        } // end if FRUITS POSITION
                    } // end for FRUITS

                    break;

                }// END SWITCH
            } // IF OUTER

        } // OUTER FOR LOOP

        return selectedspinnerFoodNameRow1;

    }// end METHOD GET FOODNAME ROW1

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
            boolean handledHere = false;

            final int action = ev.getAction();

            final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
            final int evY = (int) ev.getY();
            int nextImage = -1;

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
            if (imageView == null)
                return false;

            Integer tagNum = (Integer) imageView.getTag();
            int currentResource = (tagNum == null) ? R.drawable.background_food_tracker : tagNum.intValue();

            switch (action) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                if (currentResource == R.drawable.background_food_tracker) {

                    handledHere = true;

                } else
                    handledHere = true;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                int touchColor = getHotspotColor(R.id.image_areas, evX, evY);

                ColorTouchAreas ct = new ColorTouchAreas();
                int tolerance = 25;
                nextImage = R.drawable.background_food_tracker;

                if (ct.closeMatch(Color.RED, touchColor, tolerance))

                {


                    // GET INPUT EDIT INFORMATION ENTERED IN GRAMS
                    textInputRow1 = editRow1.getText().toString();

                    // VALIDATION NOT EMPTY FIELD EDITTEXT
                    if (textInputRow1.equals(""))

                    {
                        MainActivity.mpButtonSumit.start(); // sound

                        tToast("Please Enter Weight Of Grams For " + foodNameTempRow1);
                    }

                    else {

                        // SELECTS THE TYPE OF FOOD CATEGORY
                        switch (foodCategoryTempRow1) {

                        case "OILS":

                            // tToast("CLICK OILS ROW1"); // TESTING


                            for (int i = 0; i < oilsFoodInformation.length; i++) {

                                if (foodNameTempRow1.equals(oilsFoodInformation[i])) {

                                    MainActivity.mpButtonSumit.start(); // sound

                                    // tToast("STRING VALUE= " + textInputRow1);


                                    if (!"".equals(textInputRow1)) {


                                        gramsEditTextInputParseRow1 = Integer.parseInt(textInputRow1);

                                        // tToast("INT VALUE= " +
                                        // String.valueOf(gramsEditTextInputParseRow1));
                                        // //TESTING


                                        resultIntProteinRow1 = (double) (gramsEditTextInputParseRow1
                                                * proteinInfoRule3Row1);
                                        resultIntProteinRow1 = (int) Math.round(resultIntProteinRow1); 
                                        // MAKE CALCULATION CARBS
                                        resultIntCarbsRow1 = (double) (gramsEditTextInputParseRow1 * carbsInfoRule3Row1);
                                        resultIntCarbsRow1 = (int) Math.round(resultIntCarbsRow1); 
                                        // MAKE CALCULATION FAT
                                        resultIntFatRow1 = (double) (gramsEditTextInputParseRow1 * fatInfoRule3Row1);
                                        resultIntFatRow1 = (int) Math.round(resultIntFatRow1); 
                                        // MAKE CALCULATION CALORIES
                                        resultIntCaloriesRow1 = (double) (gramsEditTextInputParseRow1
                                                * caloriesInfoRule3Row1);
                                        resultIntCaloriesRow1 = (int) Math.round(resultIntCaloriesRow1); 
                                        // PARSE BACK FROM INTEGER TO STRING TO SET
                                        // THE TEXT WHEN CLICK BUTTON IS CLICED
                                        textInputRow1ResultProtein = Integer.toString((int) resultIntProteinRow1);
                                        textInputRow1ResultCarbs = Integer.toString((int) resultIntCarbsRow1);
                                        textInputRow1ResultFat = Integer.toString((int) resultIntFatRow1);
                                        textInputRow1ResultCalories = Integer.toString((int) resultIntCaloriesRow1);

                                        // CONCATENATE INFORMATION IN ROW 1
                                        concatenateInfoRow1 = textInputRow1ResultProtein + " - " + textInputRow1ResultCarbs
                                                + " - " + textInputRow1ResultFat + " - " + textInputRow1ResultCalories

                                        ;

                                        // CREATE KEY ROW1
                                        keyRow1 = currentDateString + "-" + "keyRow1"; /
                                        sharedPrefStoreInfo = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

                                        // now get Editor
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefStoreInfo.edit();

                                        // put your value the key would be current
                                        // date + keyRow1
                                        editor.putString(keyRow1, concatenateInfoRow1);

                                        // commits your edits
                                        editor.commit();

                                    } // end if initial edittext is empty

                                    textViewProteinRow1.setText(textInputRow1ResultProtein);

                                    // CARBS GRAMS
                                    textViewCarbsRow1.setText(textInputRow1ResultCarbs);

                                    // FAT GRAMS
                                    textViewFatRow1.setText(textInputRow1ResultFat);

                                    // CALORIES GRAMS
                                    textViewCaloriesRow1.setText(textInputRow1ResultCalories);

                                } // end if Oils

                            } // end for Oils

                            break;

                        case "FRUITS":


                            for (int i = 0; i < fruitsFoodInformation.length; i++) {
                                if (foodNameTempRow1.equals(fruitsFoodInformation[i])) {

                                    MainActivity.mpButtonSumit.start(); // sound

                                    // tToast("STRING VALUE= " + textInputRow1);

                                    if (!"".equals(textInputRow1)) {

                                        gramsEditTextInputParseRow1 = Integer.parseInt(textInputRow1);


                                        resultIntProteinRow1 = (double) (gramsEditTextInputParseRow1
                                                * proteinInfoRule3Row1);
                                        resultIntProteinRow1 = (int) Math.round(resultIntProteinRow1); // ROUND
                                                                                                        // UP
                                                                                                        // VALUE

                                        // MAKE CALCULATION CARBS
                                        resultIntCarbsRow1 = (double) (gramsEditTextInputParseRow1 * carbsInfoRule3Row1);
                                        resultIntCarbsRow1 = (int) Math.round(resultIntCarbsRow1); // ROUND

                                        resultIntFatRow1 = (double) (gramsEditTextInputParseRow1 * fatInfoRule3Row1);
                                        resultIntFatRow1 = (int) Math.round(resultIntFatRow1); // ROUND

                                        resultIntCaloriesRow1 = (double) (gramsEditTextInputParseRow1
                                                * caloriesInfoRule3Row1);
                                        resultIntCaloriesRow1 = (int) Math.round(resultIntCaloriesRow1); //                     
                                        textInputRow1ResultProtein = Integer.toString((int) resultIntProteinRow1);
                                        textInputRow1ResultCarbs = Integer.toString((int) resultIntCarbsRow1);
                                        textInputRow1ResultFat = Integer.toString((int) resultIntFatRow1);
                                        textInputRow1ResultCalories = Integer.toString((int) resultIntCaloriesRow1);

                                        // CONCATENATE INFORMATION IN ROW 1
                                        concatenateInfoRow1 = textInputRow1ResultProtein + " - " + textInputRow1ResultCarbs
                                                + " - " + textInputRow1ResultFat + " - " + textInputRow1ResultCalories

                                        ;

                                        // CREATE KEY ROW1
                                        keyRow1 = currentDateString + "-" + "keyRow1"; 

                                        sharedPrefStoreInfo = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

                                        // now get Editor
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefStoreInfo.edit();

                                        editor.putString(keyRow1, concatenateInfoRow1);

                                        // commits your edits
                                        editor.commit();

                                    } // end if initial edittext is empty

                                    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                    textViewProteinRow1.setText(textInputRow1ResultProtein);

                                    textViewCarbsRow1.setText(textInputRow1ResultCarbs);

                                    textViewFatRow1.setText(textInputRow1ResultFat);

                                    textViewCaloriesRow1.setText(textInputRow1ResultCalories);

                                } // end if FRUITS

                            } // end for FRUITS

                            break;



                } // END HAND SUBMMIT RED IMAGE BUTTON

                else if (ct.closeMatch(Color.WHITE, touchColor, tolerance)) 
                    nextImage = R.drawable.background_food_tracker;
                ;
                if (currentResource == nextImage) {
                    nextImage = R.drawable.background_food_tracker;
                }
                handledHere = true;
                break;

            default:
                handledHere = false;
            } // end switch

            if (handledHere) {

                if (nextImage > 0) {
                    imageView.setImageResource(nextImage);
                    imageView.setTag(nextImage);
                }
            }
            return handledHere;
        }// end
                                                                                                            // Method

    public int getHotspotColor(int hotspotId, int x, int y) {

        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(hotspotId);
        if (img == null) {
            // Log.d ("SubMain", "Hot spot image not found");
            return 0;
        } else {
            img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap hotspots = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getDrawingCache());
            if (hotspots == null) {
                // Log.d ("ImageAreasActivity", "Hot spot bitmap was not
                // created");
                return 0;
            } else {
                img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                return hotspots.getPixel(x, y);
            }
        }
    }// End Method

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void tToast(String s) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, s, duration);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();

                // GET INFORMATION BACK FROM SPINNER BASED ON POSITION STORED
                sharedPrefGetInfo = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


                int positionRow1 = sharedPrefGetInfo.getInt("ROW1", 0);

                // tToast(String.valueOf(positionRow1)); //TESTING

                if (positionRow1 >= 0) {
                    // LOAD SPINNER INFORMATION ROW1
                    spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.setSelection(positionRow1);

                }


 //---------------------------------------HERE IS THE PROBLEM SETTING THE CORRECT VALUE FOR SPINNER --------------------       
      //THE SPINNER 2 IS NOT BEING SET
                Resources res = getResources();

                oilsFoodInformation = res.getStringArray(R.array.SpinnerArrayInfoOils);

                if (spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItemPosition() == positionRow1) {
                    tToast("OILS TYPE TRUE");

                    int positionRow1Oils = sharedPrefGetInfo.getInt("ROW1-OILS", 0);

                    //THIS IS THE CORRECT POSITION FOR SPINNER 2
                    tToast("POSITION FOODNAME BACK = " + String.valueOf(positionRow1Oils)); 

                    // validation
                    if (positionRow1Oils >= 0) {

                        for (int n = 0; n < oilsFoodInformation.length; n++) {

                            spinnerFoodNameRow1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                    res.getStringArray(R.array.SpinnerArrayInfoOils));
                            spinnerFoodNameRow1.setAdapter(spinnerFoodNameRow1Adapter);

                            tToast("Iteration # = " + n);
                            // LOAD SPINNER INFORMATION ROW1 OILS
                            if (n == positionRow1Oils) {

                                tToast("SPINNER FOOD NAME IS SET");
                                spinnerFoodNameRow1.setSelection(positionRow1Oils); // NOT
                                                                                    // WORKING
                            }

                        }

                    } // end if

                }
                // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

                keyRow1 = currentDateString + "-" + "keyRow1"; 
                getBackInformationRow1 = sharedPrefGetInfo.getString(keyRow1, "");

                // MAKE SURE THE ARRAY KEY IS NOT EMPTY
                if (!getBackInformationRow1.equals("")) {


                    getBackInformationParseRow1 = getBackInformationRow1.split(" - ", 4);

                    textViewProteinRow1.setText(getBackInformationParseRow1[0]);

                    textViewCarbsRow1.setText(getBackInformationParseRow1[1]);

                    textViewFatRow1.setText(getBackInformationParseRow1[2]);

                    textViewCaloriesRow1.setText(getBackInformationParseRow1[3]);

                }

        }// end class
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix my problem I just got the info stored (sharedPref) on `onStart();` and set the spinner using the position (positionRow1Oils) gotten from it, on the method selection for spinner1  `spinnerFoodNameRow1.setSelection(positionRow1Oils);`

```
public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();

positionRow1Oils = sharedPrefGetInfo.getInt("ROW1-OILS", 0);
}


public String getSelectedFoodCategoryRow1() {

    Resources res = getResources();

    String selectedspinnerFoodCategoryRow1 = (String) spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItem();

     sharedPrefStoreInfo = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    //FOOD NAME OILS ROW1
    if (spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) 
    {

       //POPULATE INFORMATION FROM STRINGS XML TO FOOD NAME SPINNERS DEPENDING ON INFORMATION ON SELECTED ON FOOD CATEGORY SPINNER ROW1
        spinnerFoodNameRow1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, res.getStringArray(R.array.SpinnerArrayInfoOils));
        spinnerFoodNameRow1.setAdapter(spinnerFoodNameRow1Adapter);


        //PRESERVE SPINNER INFORMATION ROW1
         int selectedPosition = spinnerFoodCategoryRow1.getSelectedItemPosition();
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefStoreInfo.edit();   
         editor.putInt("ROW1", selectedPosition);
         editor.commit();

         *//SET SPINNER FOODNAME OILS WITH THE INFORMATION (POSITION) GOT FROM SHARERE PREFERENCE*
         spinnerFoodNameRow1.setSelection(positionRow1Oils);


        return selectedspinnerFoodCategoryRow1;
    }
```

It seems that, when a spinner2 information is set based in spinner1 information, to preserve the information from spinner2 it should be set in spinner1 method and not on the `onStart();`

It hope it helps someone facing the same issue.